# How do i detect what device the user of my app is using

Tags: ios, device, detect

Hey guys my question is i want to detect if my user is using a iPhone 4 (For its camera flash) or any other iDevice .I know how to detect what version of iOS. or how would i detect the device has camera flash capabilities .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to simply check for the specific features you require, rather than attempt to speculate based on the device. (Otherwise future devices will require you to edit your code.)

In terms of the camera flash, you could for example use the the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)'s `isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:` method. (You'll probably want to call this after first verifying the existance of a camera via the `isCameraDeviceAvailable:` method) or the `isFlashModeSupported:` method within the [AVCaptureDevice Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thank you very much! i'll just check the specific features that the app requires and just release two applications ( one for iPhone 4 , and another for every other device) Thanks again.

Comment: @Alex Er... why not just create a single app and tweak the feature set based on the device it's running on?

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to depend on the type of the device to determine its features -- it might be that some iPhone 4's sold in other markets don't have a flash, or that some not-yet-announced device does. It's always a better idea to query for the features you're interested in rather than the particular device type.

In this case, you can call +[UIImagePickerController isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:] to determine whether a specific camera has a flash.